# Google Oauth does not accepts the Port number specified

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am creating a project in Google. The Oauth does not allow the following url and says invalid uri. How can I implement it?? The IP mentioned is amazon ec2 elastic IP

```
 Redirect URIs  

        http://54.203.58.22:3333/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback

   Javascript Origins   

       http://54.203.58.22:3333/
```